# How to make nested routes inherit properties from the parent?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Is there a way to not repeat the meta properties in the nested route.

```
{
    path: "/dashboard/users",
    component: UserIndex,
    meta: {
      layout: "UserLayout",
      title: "User Dashboard",
      middleware: [auth]
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        name: 'users',
        component: Users
      }
    ],
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably too late for an answer. But it might be of interest to someone.

**router/index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import store from "../store";

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
    ...
    your-routes-here
    ...
]

// propagate metadata recursively to child routes
function propagateMetadata(routes, meta) {
    routes.forEach(route => {
        if (route.meta === undefined) {
            route.meta = meta
        }
        if (route.children !== undefined) {
            propagateMetadata(route.children, route.meta)
        }
    })
}

propagateMetadata(routes, {})

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL,
  routes
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on which version of vue-router you are using. It seems like you are using vue-router 2.x or 3.x and the documentation suggests a different way of accessing the parent route meta object.

The meta properties from the parents were indeed merged with the child meta properties in vue-router 1.x but NOT in vue-router 2.x and 3.x.
See https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/704

The meta properties of the parents do remain in the route so the documentation suggests checking for a meta field in a global beforeEach navigation guard.
For example, using the following to get the parent's middleware meta value:

```
if to.matched.some(record => record.meta.middleware) {...}
```

See docs: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html (you might be able to add all the parent route meta properties to the child's route dynamically within such a guard, which would be a way of solving your issue but I did not test this).

Vue-router 4.x again non-recursively merges the parent and child meta properties. See docs: https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html

Also note that vue-router 4.x is designed to work with vue 3.x. At the moment `npm install vue-router` will install the 3.x version of vue-router.
For now you need to explicitly use `npm install vue-router@4` to install the 4.x version.

Comment: I don't think assigning to record.meta is possible.